# I am new in laravel and I want to announcement on homepage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Actually I want to display admin announcement or any notification on home page so when ever any user will be login with credentials detail so he or she can see announcement or notification..

please help me step by step , if possible with code logic, please do for me thank you very much

Comment: You should read a step-by-step tutorial, there are plenty around the web.

Comment: please do for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you requested for full step by step process try this
first make form in your admin panel like this

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('announcement') }}">
<label>Enter Your Announcement</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="text">

</textarea>

<select name="active_status">
    <option value="0">Deactive</option>
    <option value="1">Active</option>
</select>
  </form>
```

open your `route/web.php` make post method

```
Route::post('/announcement', [
'uses'  =>  'AdminController@postAnnouncement',
'as'    =>  announcement
]);
```

if you have AdminController and its okay if not make it with these commands

```
php artisan make:controller AdminController
```

now you can add your function for save your announcement to database

```
public function postAnnouncement(Request $request){

    $announcement = new Announcement;
    $announcement->text = $request->text;
    $announcement->active = $request->active_status;
    $announcement->save();

    return back()->with('status', 'Announcement Posted Success');
 }
```

add `use App\Announcement;` in top of your controller

now you need to make announcement table and model

```
php artisan make:model Announcement -m
```

it will generate 2 file model & migration
go to `database/migration` folder and add this line to announcement migration after

> $table->increments('id');

```
$table->string('text');
$table->boolean('active');
```

your table is  ready to migrate now

```
php artisan migrate
```

now you can show in your homepage like this 
first goto your homecontroller & add these lines

```
$announcements = App\Announcement::where('active', true)->get();
return view('home', compact('announcements'));
```

in your home.blade.php file

> //Only for Authenticated Users

```
@auth
 @foreach($announcements as $announcement)
  <p>{{ $announcement->text }}</p>
 @endforeach
@endauth
```

> //Only for Guest Users

```
@guest
 @foreach($announcements as $announcement)
  <p>{{ $announcement->text }}</p>
 @endforeach
@endguest
```

Comment: Thank you very much..this is awsome, I really apperciate you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with the help of built-in user model.

First, check if the user is **authorized** and after that, you can show the announcement section.
All this should be done in the view of your page. you can do something like this

```
@if (Auth::check())
  //show authorized content (Announcements etc.)
@else
  //show unauthorized content
@endif
```

Or you can also do this in laravel 5.6

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Also do some research for this there are plenty of examples there on the Internet.

Comment: thank you, as I am new in this so I don't know where i have to put all code in model, and for notification box, how to do code so admin announcenment will appear in notification box for all user.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@auth
// For Logged in users only
<h1> You Are Loged In</h1>

@endauth

@guest
// For Guest Users
   <h1> You  Are Guest </h1>

@endguest

@auth
//if user logged in
   <h1> You Are Loged In</h1>

@else
else guest
   <h1> You  Are Guest </h1>

@endauth
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new i don't know where i have to put all code so user can view all notfication of admin announcenment. so please help with step